# Woocommerce single product categories

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, categories

On my woocommerce webshop the single product displays all categories it belongs to by using the following code:

```
    <?php
        $size = sizeof( get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' ) );
        echo $product->get_categories( ', ', '<span class="posted_in">' . _n( '', '', $size, 'woocommerce' ) . ' ', '</span>' );
    ?>
```

Now I only want to display the top parent category and not the children the product belongs to.

I have tried a lot but nothing seems to work. Does anyone have a solutions for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
$term =  get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' );
foreach ($term as $t) {
   $parentId = $t->parent;
   if($parentId == 0){
     echo $t->slug;
   }else{
     $term = get_terms( 'product_cat', array('include' => array($parentId)) );
   }
}
```

Let me know.